# Calling non-java transformers in Spring Integration

Tags: python, spring, groovy, spring-integration

I am working in a Spring integration project and the flow is simple. I get a message from a messagechannel and forward it to my own custom written router. The router based on the message type and some external hashmap value, forwards the message to a transformer though a channel. Everything, the router and transformers are in Java. Now I have to extend my project to be able to call transformers written by non-Java languages like ruby, python, groovy etc. I have seen how non-java code in these languages can be modelled as beans within the Spring context. However, I am not sure how to call non-java transformers in Spring Integration. Any pointers or sample example/code would be very helpful.

Comment: You might have to look like Google Protocol Buffers for this. Make .proto file as per your object then using protobuf utility convert it to Java objects and use it in Spring.

Comment: Frankly, I think this is too cumbersome a solution. Core Spring already has support for Python, Groovy etc. So I think that SI will have some mechanism or some tweaking is possible  to call non-java transformers without taking recourse to Google Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `spring-integration-scripting` module; for example...

```
<service-activator input-channel="referencedScriptInput">
    <script:script 
            lang="python"
            location="org/springframework/integration/scripting/config/jsr223/Jsr223ServiceActivatorTests.py">
        <script:variable name="foo" value="foo"/>
        <script:variable name="bar" value="bar"/>
        <script:variable name="date" ref="date"/>
    </script:script>
</service-activator>
```

and

```
<transformer input-channel="referencedScriptInput">
    <script:script
    lang="ruby" 
    location="org/springframework/integration/scripting/config/jsr223/Jsr223TransformerTests.rb"/>
</transformer>
```

Documentation is here... http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#scripting